# move to file directly in cmd without exact path

Tags: cmd, command, cd

I'm in C:\ folder. Then type cd Sublime Text 3, in order to get to Sublime Text 3, but i doesn't work. I have to type full path C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3 instead. But there are much longer nested files which path i don't know by heart. Exists any direct command or trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make yourself a shortcut script such as `go.bat`. It is somewhat cheezy, but it works.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET EXITCODE=0
IF "%1" EQU "" (ECHO usage: %0 ^<name^> & GOTO TheEnd)
IF /I %1 EQU sublime (CD /D "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3" & GOTO TheEnd)
IF /I %1 EQU other (CD /D "C:\Program Files\the\other\one" & GOTO TheEnd)
IF /I %1 EQU doit (CD /D "C:\Program Files" & GOTO TheEnd)
ECHO In %0 destination "%1" is unknown.
SET EXITCODE=1
:TheEnd
EXIT /B %EXITCODE%
```

Then, at the command prompt use:

```
go sublime
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Is there any direct command or trick?

You can make use of tab completion.

- Pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> key will try and complete the first matching item.
- Pressing the <kbd>tab</kbd> again will cycle through matching items if there are more than one.

So do the following when you are in the `c:\` folder:

```
type            result
cd pr<tab>      C:\>CD "Program Files"
\               C:\>CD "Program Files"\
s<tab>          C:\>CD "Program Files\Sony"
<tab>           C:\>CD "Program Files\Sublime Text 3"
<enter          You are in the correct directory
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [Windows Command Line Auto Completion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ddysart/2006/08/03/windows-command-line-auto-completion/)
- [Use Tab Completion to Type Commands Faster on Any Operating System](http://www.howtogeek.com/195207/use-tab-completion-to-type-commands-faster-on-any-operating-system/)

Comment: I still have to know at least first letter of each subdirectory.

Comment: @SaigonDrake Shrug. It's about the same number of keystrokes as `go sublime` and more useful as well.

Comment: It is very helpful to drag & drop an objective folder to cmd instead of typing  the address manually.